# Opening in Checkpoint firewall

Tags: networking, checkpoint

I have a server with address `80.39.X.X` that I want to give access to another server range in my network: `10.1.16.0/24`.

They are both in my network, behind a Checkpoint firewall.

When I try to reach this server from one of the others, I get a drop on a rule in the firewall that we have set that states:

```
Any Source, to any destination, any traffic on any service will be dropped.
```

This is a rule we have to have, since this is for a costumer.

What I'm not sure about is what rule should I set above this rule, to give the servers with `10.1.16.0/24` access to my `80.39.X.X` server?

Comment: I didn't know that costumers need special rules.  Is this the same for milliners and haberdashers?

Comment: Umm... how about 10.1.16.0/24 to 80.39.x.x ANY traffic ALLOW? I mean seriously, do you have any clue as to how to create a firewall rule and what type of rule you need to create?

Answer (score 0):

The Check Point firewall rules are matched sequentially in order (as in most of the firewalls). If you put any rule after

```
Any Source, to any destination, any traffic on any service will be dropped.
```

the rule will not apply. In fact during policy verification the management server will show you an error message that the added rule is hidden by the *any drop rule*.

You have to add the following rule before the *any drop rule*:

```
source: 80.39.x.x; destination: 10.1.16.0/24; service: any; action: allow
```

Of course you can make the destination range smaller as needed and the services can be limited as needed.